# Не меняется язык ввода, хотя раскладка поменялась при удаленном подключении к ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

Подключаюсь к удаленному компьютеру (ubuntu) по xrdp из mac os или windows по microsoft remote descktop . И при переключении раскладки не меняется язык ввода, то есть вводит на английском хотя выбран русский язык. При выборе английского так же английский и выводится. Если с компом напрямую работать, то там нормально переключается язык.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То что вы отправляете удаленно, то и принимает другая сторона. Думаю RDP просто отправляет текст из вашего языка ввода, а не языка, который установлен на Ubuntu.

Comment: Но ведь ubuntu показывает что выбран другой язык.

Comment: На каком языке будет ваша раскладка, то и тот язык будете отправлять на другой конец. Попробуйте альтернативы RDP, например TeamViewer или что то другое.

Comment: насколько мне известно, по протоколу rdp (remote desktop protocol) отправляются не скан-коды клавиатуры, а результаты трансляции — символы. т.е. для отправки символов другого языка надо переключать язык в хост-системе, а не в той, что подключена по rdp.

Comment: Так не работает. Нужно переподключаться снова. А на лету не работает

Comment: Вы как то решили вашу проблему? У меня та же самая история.

Answer (score 1):

Если заходите на машину с Ubuntu из Windows через Remote Desktop Connection, то при настройке соединения на закладке Local Resources можно выбрать установки переключения клавиатуры на местной, на удаленной или только при полном экране.

Answer (score 0):

Ради интереса попробовал. Какой язык установлен на удаленной машине, не играет роли. Тот язык, который установлен локально, на том и будет печатать. Это с RDP, а с Chrome RD наоборот, печатает на языке установленном на удалённой машине.